# Find Line of Text in Textarea With Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I saw some code a couple of days ago but I can't find it again. I have a textarea and there is [source] word inside the textarea. I want to find this word's line.

Code was like this:

```
document.getElementById('').value.match(/[source]/i).length
```

However I miss the code and I can't find it again. I don't want to do with loop. It was really easy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
   content = "foo\n bar [source] baz\n quux"
   content.match(/.*\[source\].*/)[0]
   // " bar [source] baz"
```

To find a line number (without loops)

```
 line = content.match(/[\s\S]*(?=\[source\])/)[0].replace(/[^\n]/g, "").length
```

Although a loop would be definitely more readable.

Comment: Thank you but it is in textarea and I want to get line.

Comment: @Ayro: what are you trying to do, ultimately?

Comment: This answer does get the line. Perhaps you meant to say you want the line number.

Comment: I have a textarea and I want to find word's line number. @thg435

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all; you spelled "Source" wrong in your example. When searching for exact matches, you want to get the spelling correctly.

Also; it would help a lot if you told us in what context you would like to find "[source]" inside a textarea. Because; if you know it's there, why do you need to find it?

Comment: I have textarea and there is [source][/source] part in it. I'm adding source's number, link and head. You can think, it is references (like wikipedia). I have to get [/source] line ; then I'll add more source information in it. I'm doing with for loop but I remember there was short version, I was try it but I miss the code.